# How to call Firebase Cloud Function from an external admin service account & authenticate the request on the FCF

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

**I have:**

1 - a Node service (not on Google/Firebase) with access to 'firebase-admin' functions for Firebase Project X

2 - an https.onRequest() Firebase Cloud Function for the same Project X

**What's the right way for the caller to prove to the Cloud Function that it is coming from a server with admin rights on the project?**

There are all kinds of interesting things I can do here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth

But none of them seems to be creating a token I can send to a Firebase Cloud Function, which Function can use that token to verify that the request is coming from an admin service account.

There are workarounds (e.g., through firebase-admin the Node app could retrieve the value of a field in a special Firestore "security" document maintained through another Cloud function on a cron job, and inaccessible to non-privileged users.)

But that's a weird hack to have to do to prove to a Firebase Cloud Function that the caller is a Firebase Admin service account.

**Is there a better way?**

NOTE: When I look for answers I see a lot of good, solid answers to a *different* question, where the Node API is responding to a Firebase user's request (which can contain a client-generated Firebase JWT). This question is different because I do not have a specific Firebase user token. (Use case: I'm polling the Cloud Function for unclaimed Jobs that can be initiated by any user, and can be claimed by more than one Node server).

Answer (score 1):

If you trust that:

1. No attackers can see the code running on the client server
2. No one can sniff the HTTPS traffic to and from the function (they can't)
3. No one can observe the code running in Cloud Functions

then it will be sufficient to send a special token or string of your choice in the request in order for the function in order to authorize the caller.  Since no one can see the origin or the data in transit, it should be secure enough.  This is effectively requiring the call to contain a "password" that only you and your code can see.

If you want something more robust, based on Google Cloud conventions, you can use the Cloud console to configure which service accounts can access the function, and arrange for the credentials of that service account to be sent along in the request.  The documentation for this can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating).